# Threading Explanation using runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand the threading in java. i came under this code but again i got confused whether all the threads will start all together or one by one ?
So, if someone can explain me in detail the working of this simple code then it will be really helpful for me.
Thank you in advance .

Code below:

```
public class Threadtom3 implements Runnable {

    Thread t;

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) {

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  " + i);
            try {
                // thread to sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Threadtom3());
        // this will call run() function
        t1.start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Threadtom3());
        // this will call run() function
        t2.start();

        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Threadtom3());
        t3.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: one by one, triggered by start()

Answer (score 2):

The execution order of code inside a thread is always as defined by the source code, but execution order between threads is not. That means:

- The main thread creates three instances of `threadtom3` and starts the threads one by one
- The three threads execute the `run` method as soon as they are started, so they will run parrallel but they are not aware of each other
- You have no chance to know in what order the threads execute code, as there is no defined order when the threads are interrupted and continued. It may seem like that because of the long `Sleep` statement, but you really don't know. You also don't know for example if the `run` method of `t1` is executed before `t2` is created or vice versa.

I hope this helps you understanding how threading works

Comment: Thankyou, Other thing is that lets say thread t1, t2 and t3 have started as soon as possible and when sleep method is called just after that what happen ?. Do the t1.start or t2.start or t3.start again gets executed ? or now the whole thing is in the hands of public void run() method, which ever the thread ll get executed first ?
I guess you got my question.

Comment: after the `main`-method is finished, the main thread has nothing to do any more, there is no reason why it should call `t1.start()` again. t1, t2 and t3 are each executing `run()` on their own, not knowing of any other thread. which threads executes a line first can not be predicted, it depends on when which thread is notified to continue running

Comment: yes, like different instances of microsoft word can coexist but do different things. Maybe you should look at some blog or tutorial explaining what threading is. Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask about every aspect of threading at the same time, that would simply be too broad for the concept of this website

Comment: Re, "The three threads execute the run method as soon as they are started,"  It would be more accurate to say that the operating system will run them as soon as it's scheduling rules permit.

Answer (score 1):

When `Thread.start()` is called parallel processing begins on that thread. However, there is no guarantee when the `run` method gets called.

Comment: My question is. lets say that t1 started first then will the public void run() method called ? and it goes to sleep for 1 sec? then just after this t2 is called without knowing the occurrence of t1 a again public void run() gets executed and t2 goes to sleep for 1 sec??

Comment: @KuldeepSingh - *there is no guarantee **when** the run method gets called*

Comment: means, output will be different for each time. But i guess it is fix that a thread will not get executed twice and one is executed only once?

Comment: @KuldeepSingh, output _could_ be different each time, or could be the same.  There is no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

Program starts from main so there will be one deamon thread(background thread) will get started running i,e., main thread.

later you have started 3 user threads(using start()) one after the other t1, t2 t3 . **JVM does not give guarantee in these execution of threads sequence as  they(t1,t2,t3) are not aware of each other**. It can be in any way(random) whenever we execute

```
Random threads execution

    Thread-0  10
    Thread-1  10
    Thread-2  10
    Thread-0  11
    Thread-2  11
    Thread-1  11
    Thread-1  12
    Thread-0  12
    Thread-2  12
    Thread-1  13
    Thread-0  13
    Thread-2  13
    Thread-1  14
    Thread-2  14
    Thread-0  14
    Thread-1  15
    Thread-2  15
    Thread-0  15
    Thread-1  16
    Thread-2  16
    Thread-0  16
    Thread-0  17
    Thread-1  17
    Thread-2  17
    Thread-0  18
    Thread-2  18
    Thread-1  18
    Thread-0  19
    Thread-2  19
    Thread-1  19
```

Comment: The main() thread of a Java application is *NOT* a daemon.  A Java program can not run unless it has at least one application thread that is not a daemon.  That's what "daemon thread" means:  It means, "a thread that doesn't prevent the application from quitting."  When an application starts up, it has only one application thread, so that thread had better not be a daemon, or else the application would not be able to run at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are four threads here. First the main thread - that every java program has - is started by the jvm itself. You can consider the main method as the first run() method.

When the main thread hits the first start() mathod, the second thread is created which executes the run() method.

From here on - you cannot tell for sure which of the two existing threads will be faster, because that is handled by the concrete implementation of the jvm. This means you can not tell if the run-methods for-loop or the creation of the thread t2 will be next.

The main thread will continue to create the thread t2 and t3 while the run methods of first the thread t1 executes accompanied by the corresponding run()-methods of t2 and t3.

While the for-loops of the three created threads t1 - t3 are competing according to the jvm sheduler rules, the main thread waits until all objects are deleted, which will be the case when all three run()-methods are finished and all therefore the instances of the three created threads are destroyed.

Therefore the creation of all four threads is linear, the main thread will last untill all other threads are closed down, but the order in which the three explicitly created threads are closed is somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: Re, "the main thread waits until all objects are deleted...".  No it doesn't!  Where do you see that?  The main() method starts three threads and then it returns.  As soon as it returns, the main thread is dead, and only the three new threads remain.

Comment: Yes right. The VM doesn't just wait for the main thread to finish, it waits for all non-daemon threads to finish, including the main thread. The main thread itself terminates immediately after finishing the main method.

Answer (score -1):

with the call start() the run() method of Runnable is asynchronously  executed. This means that all 3 threads could but must not run at the same time.

Comment: My question is. lets say that t1 started first then will the public void run() method called ? and it goes to sleep for 1 sec? then just after this t2 is called without knowing the occurrence of t1 a again public void run() gets executed and t2 goes to sleep for 1 sec??

Comment: The run() is called with t1.start(). Then t1 waits for one sec in its run() method. T2 does not wait for the sleep of t1, because it does not know about t1's run method. T2 starts with t2.start and waits for its own sleep of 1sec in the run()method. Same happens for t3.